# Getting unknown property: frontend\modules\printinvoice\models\Prodfin::productcode

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to print an invoice in yii2. There are two tables which I'm touching two tables. One is prodfin - where the totalamount is stored and prodsummary where the products and quantities are stored. Now I want to pass these to my view and print to pdf using mpdf. I am using prodfin as primary model and get prodsummary data attached to it. My main obstacle now is to pass prodsummary details i.e. - productcode, productname, quantity,rate, amount in place row by row. I'm attaching a sample with this.

What I'm trying to achieve -

[image]

My Controller Action

```
public function actionPrintinvoice($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new ProdfinSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Prodfin::findOne($id);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Prodsummary::find()->select(['productcode','productname','qty','rate','amount'])->where(['prfinid' => $id]),
            'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
                ],
        ]);
        $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printInvoice', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'data'=> $data,

            ]);
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Invoice'],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Private and Confidential'], 
                'SetFooter'=>['This Payslip is computer generated.'],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

    }
```

My view.php (partialview)

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\printinvoice\models\Prodfin */

$this->title = $model->prfinslno;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Prodfins', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="ps-details">
    <div style="width:38%; float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:2;margin-left:2;"><strong><p class="text-left">M/S. My Company</p></strong></h3>
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:2;"><p class="text-left">My details</p></h5>
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:2;"><p class="text-left">My Address</p></h5>
    </div>
        <div style="width:61.25%; float:right;border:1px solid black;">
            <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>PAN No.</td>
                <td>AGZPD/2365A</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice No.</td>
                <td><?php echo $model['invoiceno'];?></td>
                <td>Date : </td>
                <td><?php echo $model['date'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Challan No.</td>
                <td><?php echo $model['challanno'];?></td>
                <td>Date : </td>
                <td><?php echo $model['date'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Order No.</td>
                <td><?php echo $model['orderno'];?></td>
                <td>Date : </td>
                <td><?php echo $model['date'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="orient-details">
    <div style="width:100%; float:center;border:1px solid black;">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:2;margin-left:2;"><strong><p class="text-center">My Company</p></strong></h3>
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:2;"><p class="text-center">A Division of My Company</p></h5>
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:2;"><p class="text-center">My Address</p></h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-details">
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'productcode',
        'productname',
        'qty',
        'rate',
        'amount:ntext'
        //'ativo',
    ],
]) ?>
</div>
<div class="prodfin-view">

    <!-- <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1> -->


<!-- <strong>Using display: inline-block; </strong><br>
    <table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid";><font face="Calibri";size="72">M/S P.S. Enterprise</font></td>
            <td>This One will contain the Invoice details</td>
        </tr>
    </table> -->
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'prfinslno',
            'invoiceno',
            'challanno',
            'orderno',
            'amount',
            'date',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Please let me know how to set the gridview with the details in the middle in picture.

Model Prodfin -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\printinvoice\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "prodfin".
 *
 * @property string $prfinslno
 * @property string $invoiceno
 * @property string $challanno
 * @property string $orderno
 * @property string $amount
 * @property string $date
 */
class Prodfin extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'prodfin';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['invoiceno', 'challanno', 'orderno', 'amount'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'prfinslno' => 'Prfinslno',
            'invoiceno' => 'Invoiceno',
            'challanno' => 'Challanno',
            'orderno' => 'Orderno',
            'amount' => 'Amount',
            'date' => 'Date',
        ];
    }
}
```

Model Prodsummary

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\printinvoice\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "prodsummary".
 *
 * @property string $prid
 * @property string $productiondate
 * @property string $invoiceno
 * @property string $challanno
 * @property string $orderno
 * @property string $productcode
 * @property string $productname
 * @property string $unit
 * @property string $qty
 * @property string $rate
 * @property string $amount
 */
class Prodsummary extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'prodsummary';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['productiondate'], 'safe'],
            [['invoiceno', 'challanno', 'orderno'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['productcode', 'amount'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['productname'], 'string', 'max' => 80],
            [['unit', 'qty', 'rate'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'prid' => 'Prid',
            'productiondate' => 'Productiondate',
            'invoiceno' => 'Invoiceno',
            'challanno' => 'Challanno',
            'orderno' => 'Orderno',
            'productcode' => 'Productcode',
            'productname' => 'Productname',
            'unit' => 'Unit',
            'qty' => 'Qty',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
            'amount' => 'Amount',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the productcode using dataProvider based on Prodsummary

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Prodsummary::find()->select(['productcode','productname','qty','rate','amount'])->where(['prfinid' => $id]),
 ..
```

but you use the field productcode in a detailview  using a $model ..  the $model var don't contain the class Prodsummary  but seems came from `$model = $this->findModel($id);`

```
  <div class="product-details">
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'productcode',
        'productname',
        'qty',
        'rate',
        'amount:ntext'
        //'ativo',
    ],
]) ?>
</div>
```

so you should pass the proper value for the detailview

You have passed the te view the $datProvider related to Prodsummary. A data provider return a collection of models but you want use these data in a widget that show only a single model.
So if you want show only the first  model of dataProvider   you shoudl use

```
  <div class="product-details">
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $dataProvider[0],
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'productcode',
        'productname',
        'qty',
        'rate',
        'amount:ntext'
        //'ativo',
    ],
]) ?>
</div>
```

if you instead want show all the models in data provider  then should use an iteration

```
foreach ($dataProvider as $key => $model ) {

  echo  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'productcode',
        'productname',
        'qty',
        'rate',
        'amount:ntext'
        //'ativo',
       ],
    ]) ;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I am not so sure how to do it. Can you please tell?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I'll tell you later, first you should take off my personal curiosity. Why tackle problems rather complex and articulated with a knowledge of the framework yii2 (in my opinion) quite modest .. it seems that you know very little the  code that posted  in your questions ..I would like to know these things ..